# Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, json.net, .net-assembly

I have a console application that I am attempting to deploy to an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012R2). The console application creates a CSharp compilier instance and processes C# scripts that are sent to it.

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

The console application works as intended on my development machine. However, when I attempt to deploy it and then run on the destination server I get the following error.

```
Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be found
```

Now the assembly `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is present in the debug folder of my application with all of the other assemblies used by the application. It just cannot seem to find it. I even tried installed `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` into the GAC on the target server with the same results. When I try and hard code a path to the assembly as such

```
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("@"C:\MyApp\debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

I get an `access denied` error. I have tried everything I can think of but cannot figure out why the application cannot find the assembly.

Notes:

- I deploy this application by copying the entire debug folder over to the target server. The executable and assemblies are located in the same directory.
- The target server does not have Visual Studio or any of it's tools installed on it.
- I have the JSON.Net `nuget` package installed in the console application project on my DEV machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked. On my target machine I copied `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to the `\windows\system32` directory (on my machine it was `C:\windows\system32`) and it was found by the application.

I am not sure why loading the assembly in the GAC did not work on this solution did.

Comment: It is not a good solution, how we will copy that in hosting computer's system32 folder, In my case it works perfectly in local computer but not worked in published computer